# Realm for webservice

Tags: realm

I have a really simple question yet not answered (I think) in realm documentation. I am buildint and App that does have API + iOS App + Android App + Web. The web also needs to access to the API and here comes my question:

If I migrate to realm for iOS, Android and api, would it be possible to use it for the web through any type of calls? If so, could you give me some links or documentation to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to using the Realm Object Server as your backend. Right now, the server does not offer a web interface, such as a built-in REST API.

Instead, you could build this with the enterprise edition that offers a Node.js SDK where you can access the Realm data server-side. You could create REST endpoints and then retrieve/apply data via the Node.js SDK. Any change that came in through the REST API would then be automatically synced to the mobile clients.

Comment: I don't really need a "Backend" to access the information through a web interface but I need to be able to call that Realm Object Server so that it returns me JSONs with the information that I may need to make my own web interfice for my users. Is that possible ? Or I still need the comercial version ?